# Calling External Application Method from C# Script

Tags: c#, scripting

I've made a lot of progress on integrating scripting functionality into an application my group built, but I'm a bit stuck at the moment.

We have data acquisition software we've written (the application) that we would also like to have scripting functionality. I have embedded a class within the application that is able to read and compile externally written scripts. For example, I can write a .cs file that is not in any way linked to the application, and call the file at runtime, successfully executing it.

What I need to do now to extend the usefulness of my scripts is call pre-existing methods within the application from the script. I'll try to describe all of this with the following example:

Here I have my script file that I'm free to change at any time while the application runs

**ScriptFile.cs**

```
namespace SimpleScripts
{   
    public class MyScriptMul5 : ScriptingInterface.IScriptType1
    {
        public string RunScript(int value)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World! This works!");

            //NEED THIS: Code to call pre-existing method in application
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for this large code block, but I thought I would just include everything in case questions arise. All I want to do is call the method **TestExternalCall** with the above script, while running it through this script handler.

**ScriptHandler.cs**

```
namespace ScriptingInterface
{
    public interface IScriptType1
    {
        string RunScript(int value);
    }
}

namespace ScriptingExample
{
    public static class ScriptingEx
    {
        public static void StartScript()
        {

            string path = @"TestScript1.cs";

            // Open the file to read from.
            string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);

            Assembly compiledScript = CompileCode(readText);

            if (compiledScript != null)
            {
                RunScript(compiledScript);
            }
        }

        static Assembly CompileCode(string code)
        {
            Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider csProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();

            CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();
            options.GenerateExecutable = false; 
            options.GenerateInMemory = true; 
            options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            // Compile our code
            CompilerResults result;
            result = csProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);

            if (result.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                // Report back to the user that the script has errored
                Console.WriteLine("Script has errored");

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Errors.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error {0}: {1}", i+1, result.Errors[i]);
                }
                return null;
            }

            if (result.Errors.HasWarnings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Script has warnings");
            }

            return result.CompiledAssembly;
        }

        static void RunScript(Assembly script)
        {
            foreach (Type type in script.GetExportedTypes())
            {
                foreach (Type iface in type.GetInterfaces())
                {
                    if (iface == typeof(ScriptingInterface.IScriptType1))
                    {
                        ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes);
                        if (constructor != null && constructor.IsPublic)
                        {
                            ScriptingInterface.IScriptType1 scriptObject = constructor.Invoke(null) as ScriptingInterface.IScriptType1;
                            if (scriptObject != null)
                            {
                                //Lets run our script and display its results
                                MessageBox.Show(scriptObject.RunScript(50));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void TestExternalCall1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions, and hopefully I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my projects I was implementing similar functionality. We worked that out by providing interface to `RunScript` method that exposes different services of runner.
It allowed script writers to mock services and test their code before submit to executor.
Another benefit from that approach is that you will catch incompatibility issues during compilation.
As an alternative solution you can use reflection but it is not strong typed and 
if your executor's services has changed you may experience issues in runtime.

For example:

**Your macros**

```
namespace SimpleScripts
{   
    public class MyScriptMul5 : ScriptingInterface.IScriptType1
    {
        public string RunScript(ScriptingInterface.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, int value)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World! This works!");

            serviceProvider.Messenger.SendMessage("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

**Assembly that contains your macro engine's API** (ScriptingInterface.dll)

```
namespace ScriptingInterface
{
    public interface IScriptType1
    {
        string RunScript(int value);
    }

    public interface IMessenger{
       void SendMessage(String message);
    }

    public interface IServiceProvider
    {
        IMessenger Messenger {get;}

        String TempDirectory {get;}
    }
}
```

**Macro compiler\executor**

```
namespace ScriptingExample
{
    public static class ScriptingEx
    {
        public static void StartScript(ScriptingInterface.IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            string path = @"TestScript1.cs";

            // Open the file to read from.
            string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);

            Assembly compiledScript = CompileCode(readText);

            if (compiledScript != null)
            {
                RunScript(serviceProvider, compiledScript);
            }
        }

        static Assembly CompileCode(string code)
        {
            Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider csProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();

            CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();
            options.GenerateExecutable = false; 
            options.GenerateInMemory = true; 


                options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            //Add references to ScriptingInterface.dll
            String pathToScriptingInterfaceDll = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ScriptingInterface.dll");
            options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(pathToScriptingInterfaceDll);

            // Compile our code
            CompilerResults result;
            result = csProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);

            if (result.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                // Report back to the user that the script has errored
                Console.WriteLine("Script has errored");

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Errors.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error {0}: {1}", i+1, result.Errors[i]);
                }
                return null;
            }

            if (result.Errors.HasWarnings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Script has warnings");
            }

            return result.CompiledAssembly;
        }

        static void RunScript(ScriptingInterface.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Assembly script)
        {
            foreach (Type type in script.GetExportedTypes())
            {
                foreach (Type iface in type.GetInterfaces())
                {
                    if (iface == typeof(ScriptingInterface.IScriptType1))
                    {
                        ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes);
                        if (constructor != null && constructor.IsPublic)
                        {
                            ScriptingInterface.IScriptType1 scriptObject = constructor.Invoke(null) as ScriptingInterface.IScriptType1;
                            if (scriptObject != null)
                            {

                                //Lets run our script and display its results
                                MessageBox.Show(scriptObject.RunScript(50));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void TestExternalCall1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I'm not seeing how if I provide interface to RunScript I could call internal methods.